# How to restore the images uploaded for imagelist control in VB 6.0

Tags: vb6, controls, imagelist

I have a VB 6.0 application which contains some images inside a imagelist control. I want to know where these images get stored in the system (because I want to use these images in another application and I don't have the images separately in the system).

So, the only way is to take the images from Visual Basic 6.0 project.
Do we have anything like resource folder similar to .Net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Start an empty project.
- Add reference (Ctrl+T) to `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 or 6.0`
- Copy/Paste image list control to `Form1`
- Rename image list control to `ImageList1`

Use this code

```
Dim lIdx As Long

For lIdx = 1 To ImageList1.ListImages.Count
    SavePicture ImageList1.ListImages(lIdx).Picture, "C:\TEMP\img" & lIdx & ".bmp"
Next
```

Comment: +1 you could just paste this code temporarily into your real project. You might even be able to run it from the Immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same problem some time ago. I ended up writing a small function in the form with the imagelist that "manually" saved each image in the imagelist to disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
' utility to save images from a VB6 imagelist - example ExtractVB6ImageListImages(ImageListModes,"ImageListModes")
Function ExtractVB6ImageListImages(myimagelist As ImageList, listname As String)
    Dim nCount As Integer
    Dim nIndex As Integer
    Dim sKey As String

    Dim temp As Image

    nCount = myimagelist.ListImages.count()
    For nIndex = 1 To nCount
        If nIndex < 10 Then
            SavePicture myimagelist.ListImages(nIndex).Picture, listname + "00" + Mid(Str(nIndex), 2) + ".bmp"
        ElseIf nIndex < 100 Then
            SavePicture myimagelist.ListImages(nIndex).Picture, listname + "0" + Mid(Str(nIndex), 2) + ".bmp"
        Else
            SavePicture myimagelist.ListImages(nIndex).Picture, listname + Mid(Str(nIndex), 2) + ".bmp"
        End If

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Almost identical to the accepted answer, which was posted over 1 year ago