# VB6 Extract Images (any kind) from a ImageList

Tags: vb6, image-manipulation, imagelist

Extract Images (any kind) from a ImageList and save it as a file with extension

[image: Imagelist]

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051859/how-to-restore-the-images-uploaded-for-imagelist-control-in-vb-6-0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you already tried using the `ExtractIcon` method? That will return an `IPictureDisp` object representing an icon of the `ListImage` item.

Then, once you have extracted the picture object, you can simply call the `SavePicture` function to save it to a file on disk.

So you could use something like the following code:

```
Dim myPic As Picture
Set myPic = ImageList1.ListImages(1).ExtractIcon
SavePicture myPic, "C:\MyIcon.ico"  '(never hardcode a path in your actual code!)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want: http://btmtz.mvps.org/gfxfromfrx/

I found pretty handy.